# Lang attribute for HTML elements in WordPress

Tags: tags, lang

We are using different languages in a single article like Bengali & English. For both we need different fonts and for that we found a solution "LANG" attribute works well when defined as 'bn' or 'en'.

But in the page builder I can not see to assign a statement or words with the LANG attribute and not even in WordPress default editor.

Please suggest me the best way to do this.

Thanks Sanny

Comment: Talking about visual composer page builder...

Comment: This does not currently look like a programming question; it looks like a WordPress question. Is your question about a programming problem?

Comment: I just need solution with the issue either it is a WordPress feature or can be accomplished with programming..